# Is this a block Toeplitz matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, block-matrices, circulant-matrices

What is the name of the following matrix?

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b & 0 \\ 
c & d & 0 \\ 
0 & a & b\\ 
0& c& d& \\ 
b & 0 & a \\
d & 0 & c\end{pmatrix}$$

It looks like a [Block Toeplitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_Toeplitz_matrices) matrix, but usually one defines those by full shifts by (in this case) $2 \times 2$ matrices. In particular, I'm interested in solving linear equations of this form. Any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: If $A$ denotes your matrix, I assume that you're looking for solutions to the matrix equation $Ax = y$.  Do you have any restrictions on the values of $a, b, c, d$ such that you are guaranteed a solution?  (In general, systems with six equations and only three unknowns are not likely to have a solution.)

Comment: You're definitely going to have to solve your problem the least-squares way (or in general ,minimize with respect to whatever other norm that you're using, but that's more complicated). At first glance I can't see how to modify QR or SVD to exploit your system's structure.

Comment: it doesn't just "look" like a block-Toeplitz matrix, it IS one! Simply define the two 2x1 blocks: [a;c] and [b;d]...

Answer (score 1):

You could call it block circulant even, which is more restrictive than Toeplitz. A block matrix does not need every block to be the same size. As Laurent wrote above: Just consider the blocks to be $2 \times 1$ matrices instead of $2 \times 2$ and you will be fine.